# Unable to get selected value from Combobox in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm running a simple piece of code wherein whenever a value is selected from the combobox, it needs to be printed in the terminal. But whenever I select a value, after pressing the Quit Button, it's not getting printed on the terminal.

Any nudge would be appreciated.

Thank you for the help

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

win = Tk()

win.geometry("200x100")
vals = ('A','B','C','CD','E','FG')

current_var= StringVar()
cb= ttk.Combobox(win, textvariable = current_var)
cb['values']= vals
cb['state']= 'readonly'
cb.pack(fill='x',padx= 5, pady=5)
IP = current_var.get()
Button(win, text="Quit", command=win.destroy).pack()
win.mainloop()
print(IP)
```

Comment: You get the value just after `cb` is created and the value should be empty string because there is no item is selected at that time.  You need to get the value after an item is selected.

Comment: There's no need to use `import ttk` if you already did `import *`.

Comment: How do I make sure that I get a value after an item is selected?

Comment: You can simply move the line `IP = current_var.get()` after `win.mainloop()`.

Comment: _"There's no need to use import ttk if you already did import *"_ - @Barmar, this is an incorrect statement.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the quit button to print the value then change it to something like this.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk


def get_value():
    IP = current_var.get()
    print(IP)
    win.destroy()
    
win = Tk()

win.geometry("200x100")
vals = ('A','B','C','CD','E','FG')

current_var= StringVar()
cb= ttk.Combobox(win, textvariable = current_var)
cb['values']= vals
cb['state']= 'readonly'
cb.pack(fill='x',padx= 5, pady=5)
IP = current_var.get()
Button(win, text="Quit", command= get_value).pack()
win.mainloop()
print(IP)
```

Answer (score 0):

@Rory's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71835980/355230) isn't quite right because the final `print(IP)` is simply printing a newline (which he probably didn't notice). To fix that the `get_value()` callback function should declare `global IP` so `IP` is no longer a variable local to the function and its value can be accessed outside the function.

The code below illustrates this and also follows the [PEP 8 - Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) guidelines more closely than what's in your question.

```
import tkinter as tk  # PEP 8 advises avoiding `import *`
import tkinter.ttk as ttk


def get_value():
    global IP
    IP = current_var.get()
    win.destroy()


win = tk.Tk()
win.geometry("200x100")
vals = 'A','B','C','CD','E','FG'
current_var = tk.StringVar(win)
cb = ttk.Combobox(win, textvariable=current_var, values=vals, state='readonly')
cb.pack(fill='x', padx= 5, pady=5)
tk.Button(win, text="Quit", command=get_value).pack()
win.mainloop()
print(IP)
```

Answer (score 0):

You get the value just after `cb` is created and the value should be empty string because there is no item is selected at that time. You need to get the value after an item is selected.

One of the way is to move the line `IP = current_var.get()` after `win.mainloop()`:

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

win = Tk()
win.geometry("200x100")

vals = ('A','B','C','CD','E','FG')

current_var = StringVar()
cb= ttk.Combobox(win, textvariable=current_var)
cb['values'] = vals
cb['state'] = 'readonly'
cb.pack(fill='x', padx=5, pady=5)

Button(win, text="Quit", command=win.destroy).pack()

win.mainloop()

IP = current_var.get()
print(IP)
```